# Express js and connect-redis

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I am currently programing a website in Express Js.I need to create a login page for my users and then store some information in persistent sessions.

For that, I decided to use express-session and for the session store connect-redis.

For now, I can create a session, but when I refresh or move on another page, the session disappears.

My Redis server (on my windows during the dev time) is on the address: `localhost:6379` and is running correctly.

app.js :

```js
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var redis = require("redis").createClient();
var login = require('./routes/login');
.....
 
// express session
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: redis, ttl: 260 }),
    secret: 'sqdsqdfqszvrqsdrvqsrfvqsefqcrqs',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use('/login', login);
```

login.js (post for the creation of the session):

```js
router.post('/', [..(validators)..], (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    req.session.user = user;
    res.redirect('/login');
});
```

login.js (get for test if the session exists):

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session.user);
    res.render('login', { title: 'login' });
});
```

I think I missed something, can you help me ?

Comment: Can you please add where you add the routes from `login.js`? From the 2nd code sample: What is `user`?

Comment: try to make  ` saveUninitialized: false` and check

Comment: i added more code to see where is the problem. I tried to put false to  `saveUninitialized` and it doesn't works better

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my mistake, don't use `res.redirect('/login');` but `res.render('/login', { title: 'login'});` as I did in get method. When you redirect, the session isn't stored, but when you render it works.

Thx all ;)